# Prefix query exercise

Tags: oracle-apex

I have here a litle exercise that I am a bit stuck with:

If I am working with the table `BE_3503_SQL01_T01.EX_Purchases`. I need to see that I don't need to prefix my table in my queries.

The thing is that I am not sure what to do.
If you have any ideas, your free to post!

Answer (score 0):

In your application options, set value of Parsing Schema to "BE_3503_SQL01_T01".

Comment: Which is a valid option when all op's objects are located in that schema. If it's just a couple of object op requires in the current schema then op should consider using a synonym. It's not clear from the question though.

Comment: As the question, so the answer

Comment: Tom, I understand it. I'm blaming the questioner